# Dask Not Showing Progress Bar

Tags: progress-bar, dask, dask-distributed

When I run this I except to see a [progress bar](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/diagnostics-local.html#progress-bar), but I don't.

```py
from math import factorial

from dask.diagnostics import ProgressBar
from dask.distributed import Client


def dask_progress():
    client = Client()
    print(client)
    m = client.map(factorial, range(10))
    with ProgressBar():
        print(client.gather(m))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    dask_progress()
```

This is the output.

```
<Client: 'tcp://127.0.0.1:65468' processes=4 threads=8, memory=17.18 GB>
[1, 1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040, 40320, 362880]
```

I see the same thing with this

```py
from math import factorial

from dask.distributed import Client, progress


def dask_progress():
    client = Client()
    print(client)
    m = client.map(factorial, range(10))
    progress(m)
    print(client.gather(m))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    dask_progress()
```

What do I need to do in order to see the progress bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ProgressBar (local) vs progress (distributed)**

As hinted at in the first answer, your first code block won't show the progress bar because you are using the distributed scheduler. The `ProgressBar` is for use with the local scheduler. See https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/diagnostics-local.html

**Terminal vs Notebook**

Your second code block does not reproduce the error for me when I run it as a Python script in my terminal. It's a very fast operation, so the progress bar only shows for a split second; but it definitely appears.

However, when I run your second code block in a Jupyter notebook, the `ProgressBar` indeed doesn't appear. If you are working in a notebook you could do this:

```
m = client.map(factorial, range(1000))
progress(m)
```

**Dask Docs**

[This section of the Dask docs](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/diagnostics-distributed.html?highlight=progress#:%7E:text=In%20the%20notebook%2C%20the%20output%20of%20progress%20must%20be%20the%20last%20statement%20in%20the%20cell.%20Typically%2C%20this%20means%20calling%20progress%20at%20the%20end%20of%20a%20cell.) might be relevant here: "In the notebook, the output of progress must be the last statement in the cell. Typically, this means calling progress at the end of a cell." I suspect that wrapping the `progress` call within a `if __name__ == "__main__":` is causing issues behind the scenes here.

Answer (score 0):

There are different progress bars for the different schedulers.

See https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/understanding-performance.html